# Mysql get MIN price, not zero, not empty

Tags: mysql, database, join

I want to get MIN price from the below tables using RIGHT JOIN and WHERE price not equal to zero and not empty based on user id. How I can get single record with MIN price based on user id in single MYSQL query.
Here is my query with just right join.

```
SELECT *
FROM SEARCH
RIGHT JOIN offers ON search.search_id=offers.search_id
WHERE search.user_id='1'
```

table name: search

```
search | search_id | user_id | datetime
1      | 1         | 1       | -
```

table name: offer

```
offer_id | search_id | price
1        | 1         |      
2        | 1         | 0     
3        | 1         | 506.1     
4        | 1         | 285.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Query will be :

```
SELECT *
FROM SEARCH
RIGHT JOIN offers ON search.search_id=offers.search_id
WHERE search.user_id='1' AND search.price > 0
ORDER BY search.price ASC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to select the minimal price, you can use the MYSQL "MIN" function. For this function you need a GROUP BY in your query.

Something like this, just edit it to your requirements.

```
SELECT *, MIN(price) as `minPrice`
FROM SEARCH
RIGHT JOIN offers ON search.search_id=offers.search_id
WHERE search.user_id='1' AND search.price > 0
GROUP BY search.search_id
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using a different join condition:

```
SELECT MIN(o.price) min_price
FROM search s
JOIN offers o ON (
  s.search_id = o.search_id
  AND o.price IS NOT NULL
  AND o.price > 0
)
WHERE s.user_id = '1'
```